# Swift / iOS. Remove few view controllers from navigation stack

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

Here is what I want to do and I am not sure is it right approach, so please give me an advise how to do it.

I have Initial VC with Navigation VC, from it I push First VC, from it I push Second VC.

Next I present (from NavigationController of Second VC) Third VC.

And now I want to remove First and Second VCs from navigation stack.

After that I expect to have such result: I dismiss Third VC and I see Initial VC

How can I get that result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove view controller from navigation stack by function:

```
navigationController?.viewControllers.removeAtIndex(*index of view controller you wanna remove*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go back to the initial view controller by calling `UINavigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: Bool)`