# Remove view controllers from stack

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller(called FirstVC) which goes to another view controller(called SecondVC) with a segue. In SecondVC, I have a `PagingMenuController` which is a paging menu library. pagingMenuController itself has view controllers to show.
code to add view controllers to pagingMenuController:

```
fileprivate var pagingControllers: [UIViewController] {
    return [viewControllerList,viewControllerMap]
}
```

code to add pagingMenuController to SecondVC:

```
addChildViewController(pagingMenuController)
view.addSubview(pagingMenuController.view)
pagingMenuController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

code to go back to FirstVC:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Every time I go to SecondVC and come back to FirstVC, there are 20MB extra memory loaded. lets suppose I'm doing this:

1. In FirstVC --- Memory: 20MB
2. go to SecondVC --- Memory: 40MB
3. go back to FirstVC --- Memory: 40MB
4. go to SecondVC --- Memory: 60MB
5. go back to FirstVC --- Memory: 60MB

Although I pop view controller(SecondVC) from navigation controller, memory doesn't go free. what should I do and what is wrong I'm doing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403873/swift-ios-remove-few-view-controllers-from-navigation-stack

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with obvious. Check your SecondVC for so called retain cycles or strong reference cycles. It might be one of these cases:

1. You use `self` in some closure in SecondVC without `weak` or `onowned` reference. So the closure has a strong reference to the view controller and vice versa.
2. You have some property (with strong reference) in SecondVC which through some other entities (with strong references too) points to SecondVC.

Because of this SecondVC can not be deallocate from the memory. And you get a memory leak. You need to break retain cycle if this is the case. Usually we do this by making one of references `weak`.

For more information read [Resolving Strong Reference Cycles Between Class Instances](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID52).

For more help please show full code of view controllers.

Comment: how can I find retain cycles?

Comment: You should inspect your SecondVC for situations that I described in the answer: closures and dependencies from another classes. Pay attention to strong references.

Also you can show us your code and I'll try to point it to you.